# Best Way to Implement Location to use as separate entity and with Facet API

Tags: 7, location

Floundering a little with trying to figure out the best way to do this.  I have a structure where Activity is a node.  Each Activity can have 1 or more Locations which I want to set up as a separate node as multiple Activities can use the same Location.

Modules used:
- Drupal 7.x
- Views 3.3 X
- Search API
- Location Module
- Facet API

- Originally, I set up the Location Module and used that as part of the Activity node in the node mode.  This was so I could then display elements of the location module in the Facet API search window.  Search or clicking on a menu is set up to show a table of results.  Then you can narrow your results by clicking on the factors in a separate block.  I am using Search API.

  - Complicating factor.  I still couldn't get distance/proximity searching working with Facet API.  Though I could get it working with a generic view where the filters are exposed.  Has anyone gotten Location Module distance Proximity working with Facets for Search API?
  - When I connect to Locations via Entity Relationship the details (address, city, state) are no longer accessible to Facet API if I use Node Location.  If I use Location CCK I can, however my data is not showing up in the view.

I'm at the point of throwing in the towel and writing my own module - anyone have any words of advice on which direction to head?

Thanks,
Elizabeth